# Powershell Calculated properties and Tee-object/Variables

Tags: powershell, variables

I'm trying to write a few scripts using calculated properties (love that feature), and I seem to have an issue when I assign variables in it, for example:

```
ls | select @{N='What';E={get-acl | Tee-Object -Variable something}},@{N="ok";E={$something}}
```

it seems that the output I'm getting is:
[image: output]

And I'm unsure if there's a way to save a variable so I can use it in a different calculated property or even just piped to the next command? ( I do know that you can use that variable in the same calculated property though.)

Thanks to anyone who helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to construct many inter-related properties and `Select-Object` is too verbose or inefficient, the idiomatic approach is to pipe to `ForEach-Object` and construct the output object manually:

```
Get-ChildItem |ForEach-Object {
  $acl = $_ |Get-Acl

  # now we can just use this local variable directly
  $isOK = Test-WhateverYouNeedToTest $acl

  # construct new object
  [pscustomobject]@{
    FilePath  = $_.FullName
    ACL       = $acl
    RuleCount = $acl.Access.Count
    IsOK      = $isOK
  }
}
```

---

> I'm unsure if there's a way to save a variable so I can use it in a different calculated property

You can't "cross-reference" the *resolved* value of one calculated property expression from another in the same call, if that's what you mean.

Property expressions are executed in their own local scope, which is why variable assignments also don't persist.

You *could* (but probably ***shouldn't***) assign to a variable in a parent scope:

```
ls | select Name,@{N='ACL';E={ ($global:something = $_ |Get-Acl) }},@{N='RuleCount';E={$something.Access.Count}}
```

I would strongly recommend against it - keeping calculated properties free of side effects will make your code easier to read and understand.

> [...] or even just piped to the next command

Again, you *could*, (but probably *shouldn't*) assign to a variable in a parent scope and use that with the downstream command:

```
ls | select @{N='ACL';E={ ($global:something = $_ |Get-Acl) }} | select ACL,@{N='RuleCount';E={$something.Access.Count}}
```

To explain why this is a bad idea, let's take this example instead:

```
function TimesTen {
  1..10 | select @{N='Base';E={$global:v10 = $_ * 10; $_}} | select Base,@{N='Tenfold';E={$v10}}
}
```

This might *appear* to work as intended:

```
PS ~> TimesTen

Base Tenfold
---- -------
   1      10
   2      20
   3      30
   4      40
   5      50
   6      60
   7      70
   8      80
   9      90
  10     100
```

But this only works as long as pipeline output from `Select-Object` isn't buffered:

```
PS ~> $PSDefaultParameterValues['Select-Object:OutBuffer'] = 4
PS ~> TimesTen

Base Tenfold
---- -------
   1      50
   2      50
   3      50
   4      50
   5      50
   6     100
   7     100
   8     100
   9     100
  10     100
```

Oops! Now you need to explicitly prevent that:

```
function TimesTen {
  1..10 | select @{N='Base';E={$global:v10 = $_ * 10; $_}} -OutBuffer 0 | select Base,@{N='Tenfold';E={$v10}}
}
```

With `ForEach-Object`, you avoid all of this.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of the $_ .<something> or $_ by itself
I meant if I want to catch a specific user, and assign it to a variable and pipe it for example in:
ls | select @{N="ACL";E={$var = (get-acl myfolder).Access.IdentityReference; get-acl }} |  <some other command using $var>

Comment: @Jonathan I mean, sure, you can do that, but what's the point - you already have `$_.ACL` available to you in the downstream command? Just trying to understand what you want to accomplish here

Comment: Can I do that? I'm unsure... my tests haven't been very conclusive... that's why I opened the question :)

Comment: @Jonathan Again, _what is the purpose, what are you trying to accomplish_? What exactly is it that you're not able to do? Can you describe the tests you've carried out, and how they defy your expectations?

Comment: Hey, I'm just attempting to understand if I can use the variables created in a calculated property somehow as I can see it having a lot of value, otherwise nothing specific

Comment: @Jonathan Calculated properties are not really meant to have side effects, they should just take an input object (via `$_`) and output some corresponding value. I've updated the answer to try and show how you _could_ do what you're asking but why you _shouldn't_, I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the great answer and patience, have a great day